# best way to create a website in NetBeans 7.0

Tags: java, netbeans

i have NetBeans 7.0 and want to create a very basic website using java for my own learning. what project type should i select in Netbeans. any quick start tutorial would be appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps.html) is a quick start for web applications.